# Bounce effect in a ComboBox QML

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to change the color of the background of the comboBox when pulling till you have a "bounce effect". Cause my background color in the comboBox is black but on the bounce effect the background of the background is white.

[image]

If it's not possible I would at least want to be able to desactivate this effect "bouncing effect".

I tried as describe [here](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qml-flickable.html#boundsBehavior-prop) but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white background you are seeing is from the `popup` property embedded in the `ComboBox`, specifically its `background.color`. To customize this, [the documentation recommends](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-combobox) you re-implement the entire `popup` as well as its `ListView` `contentItem`. Re-implementation of this type can be quite painful as you must re-implement all behaviors as well as visual characteristics. I find this to be overkill when you only want to tweak a property or two that already exists.

An easier way is to set the properties at runtime. Here is a working example that shows how to modify your "bounce effect" color as well as modify effect itself:

```
ComboBox {
    id: comboBox
    model: ["first", "second", "third"]
    delegate: Rectangle { // My remake of your black-background delegates
        color: "black"
        implicitHeight: 20
        implicitWidth: comboBox.width

        Text {
            anchors {
                centerIn: parent
            }
            text: modelData
            color: "lime"
        }
    }

    // At runtime, reach into the comboBox.popup and set the background and boundsBehavior:
    Component.onCompleted: {
        comboBox.popup.background.color = "black" // Set "bounce" background color to black
        comboBox.popup.contentItem.boundsBehavior = Flickable.StopAtBounds // Change/stop "bounce" behavior
    }
}
```